# How to tar a folder while files inside the folder might being written by some other process

Tags: bash, cron, tar

I am trying to create a script for cron job. I have around 8 GB folder containing  thousands of files. I am trying to create a bash script which first tar the folder and then transfer the tarred file to ftp server.

But I am not sure while tar is tarring the folder and some other process is accessing files inside it or writing to the files inside it.

Although its is fine for me if the tarred file does not contains that recent changes while the tar was tarring the folder.

suggest me the proper way. Thanks.

Comment: What are these files? More precisely I would like to know if we "append" or if we create new files. For example, if your files are log files, and if configure a log rotation, then a naming convention can help...

Comment: The question is what do you want tar to do when that sort of thing happens. And to realize that depending on how you tell tar to do its job it may or may not see new files at all.

Comment: @mcoolive each file has a random 16 character long name . These files might be appended or new files also can be created in the folder.

Comment: @Etan Reisner , will tar stop tarring if it encounter any change in file or the filese are being accessed by some other process. if tar continues to tar the folder, its fine for me , that much of recent changes i can avoid ( that changes will be covered in next day tarring)

Comment: I can't say for sure but I don't think it will notice changes to files it finished with, notices changes to files it is working on (and possibly restarts them), and will only notice new files if you tell it to tar the directory they are in (as opposed to using a glob). I don't think it cares at all about exclusive access as long as it can read the file.

Answer (score 1):

tar will hapilly tar "whatever it can". But you will probably have some surprises when untarring, as tar also stored the size of the file it tars, before taring it. So expect some surprises.

- A very unpleasant surprise would be : if the size is truncated, then tar will "fill" it with "NUL" characters to match it's recorded size... This can give very unpleasant side effects. In some cases, tar, when untarring, will say nothing, and silently add as many NUL characters it needs to match the size (in fact, in unix, it doesn't even need to do that : the OS does it, see "sparse files"). In some cases, if truncating occured during the taring of the file, tar will complain it encounters an Unexpected End of File when untarring (as it expected XXX bytes but only reads fewer than this), but will still say that the file should be XXX bytes (and the unix OSes will then create it as a sparse file, with "NUL" chars magically appended at the end to match the expected size when you read it).
  (to see the NUL chars : an easy way is to  `less thefile` (or `cat -v thefile | more` on a very old unix. Look for any `^@`)
- But on the contrary, if files are only appended to (logs, etc), then the side effect is less problematic : you will only miss some bits of them (which you say you're ok about), and not have that unpleasant "fill with NUL characters" side effects. tar may complain when untarring the file, but it will untar it.

Answer (score 0):

I think tar failed (so do not create archive) when an archived file is modified during archiving. As Etan said, the solution depends on what you want finally in the tarball.

To avoid a tar failure, you can simply COPY the folder elsewhere before to call tar. But in this case, you cannot be confident in the consistency of the backuped directory. It's NOT an atomic operation, so some files will be todate while other files will be outdated. It can be a severe issue or not follow your situation.

If you can, I suggest you configure how these files are created. For example: "only recent files are appended, files older than 1 day are never changed", in this case you can easily backup only *old* files and the backup will be consistent.

More generally, you have to accept to loose last data **AND** be not consistant (each files is backup at a different date), or you have to act at a different level. I suggest :

1. Configure the software that produces the data to choose **a consistency**
2. Or use OS/Virtualization features. For example it's possible to do consistent snapshot of a storage on some virtual storage...